# Handle AMI for eks node managed groups in Terraform EKS module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am using a terraform EKS MODULE. Under this module, I have eks managed node groups. Recently, I noticed that I have a new AMI version available for the nodes. I can update AMI via console. But can I somehow add this AMI in terraform? I know that this module is supporting AMI ID: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest/submodules/eks-managed-node-group. But I think when I add it, it will destroy ams mananaged nodes from a EKS module. Can I add the AMI but not destroying the eks managed nodes from EKS module?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean not re-create the resource for the managed nodes, or not not re-create the nodes themselves? You definitely must re-create the nodes themselves if you change the AMI. There would not be a way to circumvent that in AWS with TF, but the ASG and Kubernetes scheduler should handle it well automatically.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for your reply. I just want to add AMI field to my eks node group under EKS module. TF doesn't support it. If I delete it and add it again under eks node group module I would have to delete a lot of resources. So I think it's better/safer to update AMI via console.